# How To Set Default Home Page in Node.Js?

Tags: node.js

Here Is My Code I am Able To See this File Content but on refresh, not as soon i type localhost and port.

```
// Include http module,
var http = require("http"),
// And url module, which is very helpful in parsing request parameters.
    url = require("url");
 var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
 var fs = require('fs');
 var emitter = new EventEmitter;
var fdata="";
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

if(request.url=="/")
{
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      fs.readFile("xhtmlJs.xhtml","UTF-8" ,function (err, data){
           fdata=data;       
    });
    response.write(fdata+"<br/>"+request.url);
     response.end();
 }
}).listen(1234);
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask good questions. :)

Comment: Thanks For Guide Me, but I did not figured out Whats Wrong with my Question.